# MS Access 2007: "Operation not supported" error for properties CacheSize, Prepare, and StillExecuting of all queries

Tags: ms-access, stored-procedures, properties, vba, runtime-error

In Access VBA, the [properties of queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/querydef-properties-dao) include CacheSize, Prepare, and StillExecuting. I have looked at these properties for all stored queries of four different Access databases, and the request always yields error 3251, "Operation is not supported for this type of object." This happens in a loop over all queries, and it also happens if I make the request in the immediate window, such as with:

```
debug.Print CurrentDb.QueryDefs(0).CacheSize
```

The documentation linked above for query properties says it applies to Access 2013. I'm using Access 2007, but in the VBA editor, the popup list of properties that comes up when I type `CurrentDb.QueryDefs(0).` includes CacheSize, Prepare, and StillExecuting, so the problem is not that those properties are not supported in my version of Access.

Why am I not able to get the values of these properties for stored queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These properties are only supported for ODBCDirect workspaces, which are only supported in JET, not in ACE, and only for external connections.

The properties are present and documented, but that doesn't mean you can use them when querying Access itself, nor that you should use them. If you want to asynchronously execute queries, you should use ADO, not DAO.